# C# Simple Console Application Enumeration Issues

Tags: c#, console-application

I am new to C# and need some help on the below code.

This console application is supposed to store details of 5 applicants in 5 different corresponding arrays. Finally this should allow me to view the names of the applicants by means of the menu I have created after declaring my arrays. Please note that the program is not yet complete.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

  namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
 enum Qualifying {Diploma=1, Bachelor=2, Degree=3, Masters_Degree=4, PhD=5};
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] ids = new string[5];
        string[] names = new string[5];
        string[] dobs = new string[5];
        string[] yoe = new string[5];
        string[] loq = new string[5];

        bool x = true;
        while (x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Add Applicants Details");
            Console.WriteLine("2.Display Applicants names");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Search for Applicant details");
            Console.WriteLine("4.Modify Applicant details");
            Console.WriteLine("5.Exit");
            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please fill in the following: ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 ID Card noS");
                            string id = Console.ReadLine();

                            ids[i] = id;
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Full Names");
                            string name = Console.ReadLine();

                            names[i] = name;
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < dobs.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("enter 5 Date of births");
                            string dob = Console.ReadLine();

                            dobs[i] = dob;
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < yoe.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Years of experience");
                            string years = Console.ReadLine();

                            yoe[i] = years;
                        }

                            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 Levels of Qualification, Choose from the list and press the number according to the qualification held:\n1=Diploma, 2=Bachelor, 3=Degree, 4=Masters Degree, 5=PhD");

                            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                            {
                                int num=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());                              
                                {
                                if (num <= 4)
                                {
                                    loq[i] = (Qualifying)num;
                                }
                                else
                                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                                }
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("The names of the students are " + names[i]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the applicant who you like to edit");
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Input the applicants ID NUMBER for modification: ");
                        string id1 = Console.ReadLine();

                        //if (id1 == id)
                        //    Console.WriteLine("Full Name");
                        string name1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Date of birth");
                        string dob1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Years of experience");
                        int years1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Levels of Qualification, Choose from the list:\nDiploma, Bachelor, Degree, Master Degree, PhD");
                        string quals1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    }

                case 5:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You chose to quit. BYE =D");

                        x = false;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have an error in line 78 stating:

*"Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication1.Qualifying' to 'string'"*

Can anyone please provide any suggestions in order to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Luke

Comment: `loq[i] = (Qualifying)num;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
loq[i] = (Qualifying)num;
```

should be

```
loq[i] = ((Qualifying)num).ToString();
```

`loq` stores a string type and you're trying to put in an enum of `Qualifying`.